# I want to check if `id` has no content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want check between id that get in `var span`, if empty was between it put css for input but it not work. how can fix it?

```
var span = '#'+$('.valid').closest('.auto_box').find('span').attr('id');
if ($(span+':empty').length != 0) {
    //alert('ok')
    (this).closest('.auto_box').find('input').css('background-color','#000');
}
```

See here my full code: http://jsfiddle.net/Pjqv2/2/

Comment: Instead of doing all this string concatenation, you could just do: `var span = $('.valid').closest('.auto_box').find('span'); if(span.is(':empty')) {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `(this)` instead of `$('.valid')` or whatever you meant with it. Also, you are doing this the wrong way; `.find('span')` returns the jQuery objects set for that span.

You don't need to get it's ID and then check on that ID again. **More importantly**, your code seems the need to run on multiple instances of `.auto_box`. For that, you need to iterate on the set found by `(".valid").closest(".auto_box")`, which you can do with the jQuery `.each()` ([.each() in jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)) like this:

```
var autoBoxes = $(".valid").closest(".auto_box");
autoBoxes.each(function(){
    if ($(this).find("span").is(":empty")) {
        $(this).find("input").css("background-color", "#000");
    }
});
```

Your updated jsfiddle with this script: http://jsfiddle.net/dvir_azulay/Pjqv2/4/

Answer (score 0):

Change `(this)` to `$(span)`. [I updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pjqv2/3/) to reflect this change.